# Hangman Game - Repeated string issue

Tags: javascript

I was working on my Hangman game, and I have a frustrating issue where once I click the start button to start the game, dashes print to the div not only once, but many times after(once the word to guess has been inputted). I am trying to have the dashes print only once to the div. For example, for the word dog, I want --- to print, and no more dashes after start is pressed. Could you point me in the right direction? Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfn46wjm/

Here is the javascript code for where it appends to the page:

```
//loop for underscores  
//creates under scores for each letter;
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    placeholder += "-";
}

//append dashes to the page
var grab = document.getElementById("test");
var secret = document.createElement("p");
secret.id = "guessp";
var textn = document.createTextNode(placeholder);
secret.appendChild(textn);
grab.appendChild(secret);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight **exactly** what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell **exactly** what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, here is where the dashes append to the page everytime I press start:  //loop for underscores  
    //creates under scores for each letter;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        placeholder += "-";
    }

    //append dashes to the page
    var grab = document.getElementById("test");
    var secret = document.createElement("p");
    secret.id = "guessp";
    var textn = document.createTextNode(placeholder);
    secret.appendChild(textn);
    grab.appendChild(secret);

Comment: are you talking about the issue that it prints more and more dashes(in new lines) if user keeps on pressing "start"?

Comment: Yes exactly, it keeps printing more and more dashes.

Comment: just use a flag that the dashes have been printed already. :\

Comment: Is that like a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [Latest jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb3qwrtz/3/)
i added a flag `printed` and checking if it's true before printing any more dashes.

this is the updated link. please check and see if it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. However, I did notice another problem. When I enter in a correct letter, is prints the dashes continuously again.

Comment: updated. please check the updated fiddle. (it's the same in the comment). oops, another hiccup. checking it. wait please.

Comment: For some reason this time it prints one extra line of dashes. For example if I input "dog", then I press d for checking the letter, it will print an extra set of dashes along with the original set of dashes that is being changed into letters.

Comment: Check again. this should be fixed for good now. i've put some `console.log()` in there, which you can remove. apparently the loop to set up your `placeholder` was running with every hit on "start". the new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a79kcx8c/16/) .

Comment: I checked it. I went to the same link, and I see the same result. It is very  close. I'm trying to work with it as well. This is the output I get when I put in "dog": 
d--
---

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a79kcx8c/17/ is the correct link right? That's the one I've been clicking on.

Comment: In that link, I see the same problem. d-g as the first output, then under it, " --- "

Comment: the problem is, that your two functions are adding the dashes in 2 different places. the `game()` function is adding it under `div#test` and the successful guess is adding it in just `<p>`. so..which one you want to keep?

Comment: The successful guess part of it I definitely want to keep. If there was a way to combine both, that would be great.

Comment: see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sb3qwrtz/5/) works as you expect it to.

Comment: thanks alot for your persistence. i was looking at the code. other than the var printed and the if statement, what did you change?

Comment: Oh I see the local placeholder variable has done the magic! Wow!! Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
var grab = document.getElementById("test");
var secret = document.createElement("p");
secret.id = "guessp";
var textn = document.createTextNode(placeholder);
secret.appendChild(textn);
grab.appendChild(secret);
```

means that you insert your placeholder ("---") into `<div id="test"/>`.

In your `checkInput` method you're calling:

```
var spguess = document.getElementById("guessp");
```

And since in your HTML code you have:

```
<p id="guessp"></p>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Then your `checkInput` method refers to the first `<p/>` element, while at `start` you insert new `<p id="guessp"/>` to your `<div id="test">`. And then you get this error.